# Accessing a char in a String in an Arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I can access and print a string from my arraylist

```
list.get(0).getLastName();
```

but I can't access a char:

```
list.get(0).getLastName().charAt(0);
```

Even if I set `list.get(0).getLastName()` equal to a variable like str, I can print str fine, but if I try `str.charAt(0)`, it never returns anything that I can print or work with.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What `getLastName` returns?

Comment: Can you show the exact code that doesn't work and the desired output?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: and if you are getting errors , those as well

Comment: You need to assign or print output of `charAt(0)`..

Comment: Are you sure last name does not start with a space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too often I see this issue with characters that are not expected:

Maybe it starts with a space, or some other special character?

```
String lastName = list.get(0).getLastName();
System.out.println(">>"+ lastName.charAt(0)+"<<");
System.out.println("Ascii Value: "+(long) lastName.charAt(0));
```

Use a [unicode chart](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) to look-up the character.

Comment: That's definitely it!! It came up as 32, which translates to a space. So I'll try to get the next char.

Comment: Thanks again. I did charAt(1) and got my desired character.

Comment: It is so common ... where you let users enter in data, spaces appear! I am sure you will find a few that managed to put a whole love letter in the last name field ... I have seen everything ... and still I get surprises ! Or also common is copy-paste from word ... causing wrongly translated characters, or decorated versions of plain characters (like straight quotes vs left/right curled quotes).